# Python: Get Network Request Response Body

Tags: python, selenium, mozilla, geckodriver

Hello I'm trying to get network request details including headers, URL, and response. I came up with the headers and URL but not able to get response. I've followed this URL(https://www.dilatoit.com/2020/12/17/how-to-capture-http-requests-using-selenium.html). They have mentioned i can get response body but when i call request.response.body i got a string in bytes which I'm not able to decode. Please help me to get response of a request.

Comment: Do you need response code like http:200? or response text?

Comment: @TalalSiddiqui There is numerous network request after page load. From which i need the response of one.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need response text. You should try

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
url = r"https://www.dilatoit.com/2020/12/17/how-to-capture-http-requests-using-selenium.html"
page = session.get(url)
print(page.text)
```

In case you want to check web response code i.e. http 200 etc

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
url = r"https://www.dilatoit.com/2020/12/17/how-to-capture-http-requests-using-selenium.html"
page = session.get(url)
print(page.status_code)
```

Comment: Like we inspect in mozilla there's tab name network. I've got the request from there after page load but not able to get response of the same.